# PHP array from checkboxes

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

Is it possible to populate a PHP array from selected checkboxes?

The application of this is that I am building a form for registering dance students and I want them to be able to select which classes they want to register for and then submit them to a database via an array.

Also important information is that the array is inside of a PHP class.

Comment: Thanks, Marc. Would you care to share an example of how this would be done?

Comment: Also important information is that the array is inside of a PHP class.

Comment: `$foo = $_POST['fieldname'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You'd have to rename your inputs to:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="courses[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="courses[]" value="2">
```

Adding the brackets would automatically create an array on the server side given by `$_POST['courses']` for example.

And to get the selected boxes:

```
foreach($_POST['courses'] as $course) {
    // do stuff
}
```